# How to set two sources to an image in HTML depending on where the file is

Tags: php, html, image

I am making a website in PHP and have come across a problem where if I include my head.php file from a file in another directory it cannot find my logo image. I have tried including two images, that worked accept I had the file error image next to the logo as only one of the images are in a correct location. Does anybody know how I can fix this?

head.php code

```
 <div id="head">
    <div id="inner_head">
      <div id="logo">
        <img src="images/logo.png">
      </div>
      <div id="search">
        <form action='search/search.php' method='get'>
          <div id="search_feild">
            <input type="text" name="input">
          </div>
            <div id="search_submit">
                <input type="submit" VALUE="" /><div id="results"></div>
            </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <a href="user/login.php">
        <div id="login_head">
          Login
        </div>
      </a>
      <div id="nav">
        <ul>
          <li>Home</li>
          <div class="nav_mid"></div>
          <li>About</li>
          <div class="nav_mid"></div>
          <li>Teachers</li>
          <div class="nav_mid"></div>
          <li>Links</li>
          <div class="nav_mid"></div>
          <li>Links</li>
          <div class="nav_mid"></div>
          <li>Art</li>
          <div class="nav_mid"></div>
          <li>Subjects</li>
          <div class="nav_mid"></div>
          <li>Downloads</li>
          <div class="nav_mid"></div>
          <li>Media</li>
          <div class="nav_mid"></div>
          <li>Contact</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: show `head.php` code where you trying to link

Comment: If the image URL is a relative URL, it's interpreted relative to the URL of the containing document, not the location of `head.php`.

Comment: Remember that relative URLs are translated by the browser, not the server, and the browser doesn't know anything about the inlude files that were used to render the document. It just knows the original URL it accessed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not good idea to load 2 image for resolve the problem but however, I think you can use this:

```
$logo_1 = "logo 1 path";
$logo_2 = "logo 2 path";

if (file_exists($logo_1))
{
  echo '<img src="$logo_1" />';
}
elseif (file_exists($logo_2))
{
  echo '<img src="$logo_2" />';
}
```

Comment: This will cause a mess of conditionals if you're loading any other assets relatively.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably running into relative path issues. Since the file that you're alternatively calling the head from is referencing assets from its relative path, the new path is now incorrect.

-- index.php
-- head.php
-- directory
---- file.php (includes head.php) any references are now 1 directory deeper and now incorrect

To solve this, serve all assets absolutely, so you avoid any conflicts
`<img src="<?php include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/project-name/images/logo.png"; ?>" />`

Answer (score 0):

You should just create a symlink to the image file in the second location. Then you only have to worry about updating one file.

```
ln -s /myoriginalsite/images/logo.php /myothersite/images/logo.php
```

Now you just need to update /myoriginalsite/images/logo.php and both will change.

No PHP code needed.